# Matching with "if" condition for the fields, anywhere in list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a `list` of strings that contain comma separated items.

```
data = 
    [
    'dog, cat, mouse, horse', 
    'apple, mango, orange, banana'
    ]


for item in data:
  r = item.split(', ')
  if r[0] == 'dog':
     print("my animal logic goes here")
  elif r[0] == 'apple':
     print("my fruit logic goes here")

output:
my animal logic goes here
my fruit logic goes here
```

Above sample works and but as per my new problem `data2` is in `dict` kind of format, so that every field will have something like street, house, ... etc, and they are not fixed to column number: street may come in column 0, or 1, or 2, ... etc.

```
data2 = 
[
'street:dog, house:cat, house:mouse, street:horse', 
'form:apple, local:mango, form:orange, local:banana'
]
```

or may be like this, too.

```
data2 = 
[
'house:cat, street:dog, house:mouse, street:horse', 
'local:mango, form:apple, form:orange, local:banana'
]
```

My requirement is to search street (2 streets found here) and match with `'dog'` in `if` condition.

```
for item in data2:
  r = item.split(', ')
  ## here i need to search for street and then match for 'dog'
  ## street could be in column 0, 1, 2 or anywhere.
     print("it is an animal")
  ## here i need to search for fruit and then match for 'apple'
  ## fruit could be in column 0, 1, 2 or anywhere.
     print("it is a fruit")
```

Comment: Try `'dog' in r[0]` instead of `r[0] == 'dog'`

Comment: can't understand clearly what you want to do. can you explain more?

Comment: @Prayson: 'dog' in r[0] may work only if my column[0] has street:dog, but it will not work if street:dog in any other column fields... thatswhy i am not able match exactly with column numbers.

Comment: You certainly mean `r[0] == ...`.

Comment: @erip: sorry that was a typo error.. please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try and this is a potential solution.

```
formattedRecords = (rec.split(':') for item in data2 for rec in item.split(','))

for item in formattedRecords:
    if item[1] == "dog":
        print("It is an animal")
    elif item[1] == "apple":
        print("It is an fruit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged in regex, the answer will include regex in it:

```
import re

data2 = ['street:dog, house:cat, house:mouse, street:horse', 'form:apple, local:mango, form:orange, local:banana']

    for item in data2:
        r = item.split(',')

        for part in r:
            identifier, it = re.findall('(\w+):(\w+)', part)[0]
            if identifier == "street":
                print("{} found as street".format(it))
            elif identifier == "form":
                print("{} found as form".format(it))
```

output is:

```
dog found as street
horse found as street
apple found as form
orange found as form
```